# Ignoring hyphens while using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Is there any easy way to ignore hyphens while using scanner? I have a program that will allow you to buy an area (2D array) so if the user want to buy area 3-6, I want scanner to put the number before the hyphen in row and the number after in column. Is there any easy way to do this?

```
String[][] buyer = new String[10][15];
int row;
int column; 
System.out.print("Specify which area you want to buy: ");
row = scan.nextInt();
column = scan.nextInt();

String name;
System.out.print("Name of the buyer: ");
name = scan.nextLine();
buyer[row][colum] = name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your input is always in this format (num1-num2) then you can use :

```
String area = scan.next();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(area);
st.split("-");
int row = Integer.parse(st.nextToken());
int col = Integer.parse(st.nextToken());
```

Comment: Use of `StringTokenizer` is specifically discouraged in the Java API docs. It recommends using `String.split()` or `java.util.regex` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd read it as a String, then you can use `String.split()` to split it in to two values that you can then parse to ints. There may be other options though.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner has some bad and some good side, the bad side is this not work if you not know what next chars is.

You can use [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) and if not this is true, read char for char unto `hasNextInt` is true.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Scanner.skip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#skip%28java.lang.String%29)

```
row = scan.nextInt();
scan.skip("-");
column = scan.nextInt();
```